# TypeError when trying to open a workbook using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm trying to use openpyxl to open and modify an existing excel workbook, but I can't even open the file without getting an error.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
ws = load_workbook('PO-Copy.xlsx')
```

I get a long TypeError as a result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<module1>", line 6, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 151, in load_workbook
     _load_workbook(wb, archive, filename, read_only, keep_vba)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 224, in _load_workbook
      keep_vba=keep_vba)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\worksheet.py", line 308, in read_worksheet
     fast_parse(ws, xml_source, shared_strings, style_table, color_index)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\worksheet.py", line 296, in fast_parse
     parser.parse()
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\worksheet.py", line 84, in parse
     dispatcher[tag_name](element)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\worksheet.py", line 282, in parse_data_validation
     dv = parser(tag)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\datavalidation.py", line 179, in parser
     dv = DataValidation(**element.attrib)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'errorStyle'
```

Has anyone else ran into this error?  is there a fix I can use to keep going?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ability to read DataValidation in existing files was added in openpyxl 2.1 but was limited to what DataValidation in Python supported. Work has started on supporting DataValidation fully and is available in the 2.2 branch at https://bitbucket.org/habub68/openpyxl

Comment: [I downloaded & installed the 2.2 version here](https://bitbucket.org/habub68/openpyxl/downloads), but that didn't work.  However, the 2.0 version did, so that's what I'll go with.  Thanks!

Comment: 2.0 completely ignores DataValidations so go with that if you don't need them. If we can finish up the work soonish it will get backported to a 2.1 patch release. Can you file a bug report? Helps keep track of it.

I don't know if installing from a download actually works.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what is the correct way to do it?  I know of no other way to gain the functionality of openpyxl other then downloading and installing onto the machine.

Comment: You need to do a checkout of the source with Mercurial or SourceTree and then switch to the 2.2 branch and install in development mode `python setup.py develop` in a virtual environment to avoid your existing Python being affected.

The download contains an archive of the whole project but at the current state (2.1 release). We do not recommend using this to install the library ever. As the documentation says openpyxl should be installed using `pip install openpyxl`

Comment: We now have a bug that is related: https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issue/366/error-datavalidation-and-unicode-symbols